# Frames + Page Controls

Tags: delphi

I have application with 20+ windows...

At first I was using different forms (with no inheritance), 20+ of them and it used like 8 MB of RAM.

When I setup it with page controls + frames + frame inheritance, RAM usage for application is like 50 MB and app is ~ 2 MB larger.

I have noticed that when I add frame to tab, modify picture in frame, it still displays old one when opening tab. So I have to reload picture in tab itself (disk space usage drops after compiling)

So it looks like it's using twice the same components, is this a default behavior or I am doing something wrong?

I just create frame, select unit to load, drop next frame, ...

Comment: Decided to go with child forms, still, would like to know answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still some issues with frames. Updating is one of them.

I completely stopped using frames with V 7 and never missed them.

In my opinion, frames are fine for prototyping, but eventually you better create custom components. (Which are quite easy using a panel that creates its children and provides the properties for accessing them). You need more work if you want to initialize them in the form designer. But that is no rockedt science either.

Answer (score 0):

To use the frames in such manner (to create all 20+ frames and drop on tabs in pagecontrol) is bad idea. You need create the frame in run-time when tab changed (and remove/destroy from memory the previous frame).

But to keep in memory all frames/controls is bad structure for large application